# Extracting specific blocks of data from a list in between keywords

Tags: python

I am trying to extract specific portions of a list in between key words, that is everything between  and  and ignoring every thing else.

```
['badsffsg\n', 'fssdfsdgdg\n''<begin data>\n', 'data\n', '<end data>\n', 'bagsdg\n', 'fsdgdg\n', '<begin data>\n', 'data\n', 'data\n', '<end data>\n' 'gsdg\n']
```

I am having trouble figuring out how to iterate over the list. I solved a similar problem but it was for when there is only one block of data at a fixed index in a dictionary.

```
def extract_person(lines, start_index=0):

    start = start_index
    end = lines.index('<end data>\n', start_index + 1)   
    mylist = []

    for line in range(start + 1, end):
```

This time its a list, there is multiple blocks of data and it unsure where the data starts. Its just how to iterate over this that i need some advice about.

Comment: Do you really have what look like tags in there? Have you split some xml/html tag weirdly?

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable as a flag if you are currently inside a data block. Initially set the flag to`False`.

Iterate over list, when encountering block start, set flag to `True`.
If flag is `True` and list item is neither start nor end tag process list item as part of current data block. When encountering block end, set flag to `False` and maybe do some final processing for the closed data block.

Answer (score 0):

Use index method of lists to your benefit.

```
some_data = ['a', 2, 'b', 'start', 1, 2, 3, 'end']

start = some_data.index('start')+1
end = some_data.index('end')

for data in some_data[start:end]:
    print(data)
```

This outputs

```
1
2
3
```

You may add conditional tests in case of missing markers

Comment: Doesn't this only work if there is one section of data, if there is multiple it only gets the first bit

Comment: Yes, but see my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are certainly several different ways to write a solution for this. Let's forget the use of index (because it will require catching exceptions when a marker is not found; I assume you want a simple algorithm without that). The code below is actually a variation of what Michael proposes if you read both descriptions carefully:

```
data = ['a', 2, 'b',
        'start', 1, 2, 3, 'end',
        'c', 'd',
        'start', 2, 2, 5, 'end',
        10,
        'start', 5, 6 ,7, 'end']

blocks = [] # to keep valid data blocks
pos = 0
end = len(data)
while pos < end:
    if data[pos] == 'start':
        block = []
        pos += 1
        while pos < end and data[pos] != 'end': # condition order important!
            block.append(data[pos])
            pos += 1
        blocks.append(block)
    else:
        pos += 1

print(blocks)
```

Explanation:

We will collect valid data blocks in variable `blocks`.

We go through the list from beginning to `end` (and not more) using `pos` (position) to keep the current index position. Finding a `'start'` means create an empty new `block` to store the next items, until we find an `'end'` mark.

We append block data but take care that the list does not end prematurely, until we find the `'end'` mark. Condition order is important because otherwise we may try an access to `data` with an invalid (too big) index. The condition in the right of `and` operator is not evaluated if the first condition on the left is already False, so no error in that case.

We continue until the list ends.

If there is a `'start'` marker without and `'end'` marker a final empty block is left in the result `blocks` list.